# How do I Output a value of a nested object in Javascript after looping through?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm having some trouble printing out some of my data of a forEach loop. I'm working on a Twitter clone and I'm trying to loop through an object and print out the tweets for a user. I'm getting the divs to print out in the console but I can't seem to figure out to get the tweets to print inside the div.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
var user1 = {
  userName: '@elonmusk',
  displayName: 'Elon Musk',
  joinedDate: 'June 2009',
  followingCount: 103,
  tweetAmount: 18600,
  followerCount: 47900000,
  avatarURL: 'assets/elonmusk.jpg',
  coverPhotoURL: 'assets/elonmusk-cover.jpeg',
  tweets: [{
      text: 'I admit to judging books by their cover',
      timestamp: '2/10/2021 00:01:20'
    },
    {
      text: 'Starship to the moon',
      timestamp: '2/09/2021 18:37:12'
    },
    {
      text: 'Out on launch pad, engine swap underway',
      timestamp: '2/09/2021 12:11:51'
    }
  ]
};

var container = document.getElementById('container');
var midSection = document.getElementById('mid-section')
var sections = document.createElement('div');
sections.classList.add('container');

sections.innerHTML = `
    <div class="left-section"></div>
    <div class="mid-section">
        <div id="header">
            <img class="arrow" src="./assets/arrow-left.svg" />
          <div class="user-info">
            <h2>${user1.displayName}</h2>
        <div class="numberOfTweets light-text">${user1.tweetAmount}K Tweets</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cover-photo"><img src="${user1.coverPhotoURL}"/></div>
        <div id="avatar">
        <div class="profileImage"><img src="${user1.avatarURL}"/></div>
        <div class="follow">
            <button class="btn-more"><img src="./assets/three-dots.svg"/></button>
            <button class="btn-follow btn-primary">Follow</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="pl20">${user1.displayName}</h2>
        <div class="user-info2 light-text pl20">${user1.userName}</div>
        <div class="join-date light-text pl20 pt10">Joined ${user1.joinedDate}</div>
        <div class="following pl20 pt10">
        <p><span class="bold">${user1.followingCount}</span> Following</p>
        <p class="pl20"><span class="bold">${user1.followerCount}</span> Followers</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-navigation pt20">
           <div class="tabs">Tweets</div>
           <div class="tabs">Tweets & replies</div>
           <div class="tabs">Media</div>
           <div class="tabs">Likes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tweets">
      
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-section"></div>
`;

var user1Tweets = user1.tweets;

var tweetDivs = user1Tweets.map((tweetDiv) => {
  if (!tweetDiv.tweets) {
    return { ...tweetDiv,
      tweets: []
    };
  } else if (!Array.isArray(tweetDiv.tweets)) {
    return { ...tweetDiv,
      tweets: Object.values(tweetDiv.tweets)
    };
  }
  return tweetDiv;
});

tweetDivs.forEach(function(tweetDiv, i) {
  var tDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tDiv.classList.add('tweetDiv');
  tDiv.innerHTML = `

    ${tweetDiv.tweets.map(function(tweet) {
        return `<div>${tweet}</div>`
    })}
  
    `;
  //console.log(tDiv)
  midSection.appendChild(tDiv);
})

container.appendChild(sections);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="mid-section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: add your html..

Comment: Html is added @dippas

Comment: Just to let you know, `forEach()` loop can't **return** custom values. Using **return** in a `forEach()` is equivalent to a continue in a conventional loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user1.tweets` is an array. So you can iterate over the array, get the `text` from each object, and do something with it.

```js
var user1 = {
  tweets: [{
      text: 'I admit to judging books by their cover',
      timestamp: '2/10/2021 00:01:20'
    },
    {
      text: 'Starship to the moon',
      timestamp: '2/09/2021 18:37:12'
    },
    {
      text: 'Out on launch pad, engine swap underway',
      timestamp: '2/09/2021 12:11:51'
    }
  ]
};


var midSection = document.getElementById('mid-section')

user1.tweets.forEach(function(tweetDiv, i) {
  var tDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tDiv.classList.add('tweetDiv');
  tDiv.innerHTML = tweetDiv.text;
  midSection.appendChild(tDiv);
})
```

```html
<div id="mid-section"></div>
```